# discord.py Levelling System using json. How can I add these few things to my code?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py

So I have this code for a Discord levelling system where every time a user sends a message in a server that my bot is in, they gain a random amount of xp between 5 and 10. This is the code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open("users.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

        await update_data(users, member)

        with open("users.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open("users.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

        if message.author.bot:
            return
        else:
            await update_data(users, message.author)
            number = random.randint(5,10)
            await add_experience(users, message.author, number)
            await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)

        with open("users.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]["experience"] = 0
        users[user.id]["level"] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[user.id]["experience"] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    experience = users[user.id]["experience"]
    lvl_start = users[user.id]["level"]
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await bot.send_message(channel, f":tada: Congrats {user.mention}, you levelled up to level {lvl_end}!")
        users[user.id]["level"] = lvl_end
```

This works fine, but there are several things I'd like to add/change/modify to improve it. They are listed below:

a) I only want a user to get xp from messages once a minute or once every 30 seconds to prevent spam levelling up.

b) I want it to also put the server into the json file, so that way each user has a unique level for each server, because currently, their xp gets carried across all servers they and the bot share.

c) Currently, the bot also gives the user xp if the user dm's the bot, which obviously I don't want. Is there a way to stop the user getting xp if it dm's the bot, I can't just make the bot ignore dm's because for some commands the user and the bot need to use them.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated. Even if you can only answer 1 question, or give an idea or opinion, that would be great.

Thanks

ChiefJack

EDIT: I have all of my questions answered now, here they are in code, hope this helps (please don't copy my code, thanks):

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open("users.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

        if message.author.bot:
            return
        if message.channel.is_private:
            return
        else:
            await update_data(users, message.author, message.server)
            number = random.randint(5,10)
            await add_experience(users, message.author, number, message.server)
            await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel, message.server)

        with open("users.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)

async def update_data(users, user, server):
    if not user.id + "-" + server.id in users:
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id] = {}
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["experience"] = 0
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["level"] = 1
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["last_message"] = 0

async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
    if time.time() - users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["last_message"] > 30: 
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["experience"] += exp
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["last_message"] = time.time()
    else:
        return

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
    experience = users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["experience"]
    lvl_start = users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["level"]
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await bot.send_message(channel, f":tada: Congrats {user.mention}, you levelled up to level {lvl_end}!")
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["level"] = lvl_end
```

Comment: You can check `message.channel.is_private` to see if the message is private or not.

Comment: Patrick, thanks for answering. I asked someone to help after I'd posted this and they told me all the answers. I'm going to post them all now just so people know not to answer but thanks anyway!

Comment: It's okay to answer your own questions, but you should do so as an answer, not an edit to your question, and also provide a short explanation of the solution.

Answer (score -1):

This is a cog I made just today. it has all the feature you need.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import json
import os
import datetime
from random import randint

epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
time_diff = round((datetime.datetime.utcnow() - epoch).total_seconds())

class lvlup(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, ctx):
        if ctx.content.startswith('B.') is not True:

            if ctx.guild != None:

                F = open("./cogs/level.json")

                level = json.load(F)

                user_time = round((datetime.datetime.utcnow() - epoch).total_seconds())

                if str(f"{ctx.guild.id}") not in level:
                    level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"] = {}
                    print(f"Guild file has been created for {ctx.guild.id}/{ctx.guild.name}")

                if str(f"{ctx.author.id}") not in level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"]:

                    level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"{ctx.author.id}"] = {"level" : "1", "xp" : "0", "NT" : f"0", "multi" : f"1", "txp" : f"0", "starttime" : f"{user_time}"}

                if user_time - int(level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"{ctx.author.id}"]["NT"]) >= 60:
                    RNum = randint(1, 5)
                    MP = int(level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"{ctx.author.id}"]["multi"])
                    XP = int(level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"{ctx.author.id}"]["xp"]) + (RNum * MP)
                    TXP = int(level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"{ctx.author.id}"]["txp"]) + (RNum * MP)
                    LVL = int(level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"{ctx.author.id}"]["level"])

                    if XP >= 20*LVL**2:
                        XP = XP % (20*LVL**2)
                        LVL += 1

                        F1 = open("./cogs/currency.json")
                        mon = json.load(F1)

                        if str(f"{ctx.author.id}") not in mon:
                            mon[f"{ctx.author.id}"] = {"money" : "0", "hist" : "0", "multimon" : "1"}

                        RNum1 = randint(1, 25)
                        MM = int(mon[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["multimon"])
                        Money = int(mon[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["money"]) + round(RNum1 * (LVL + 1) * MM)
                        HMoney = int(mon[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["hist"]) + round(RNum1 * (LVL + 1) * MM)

                        F1.close()

                        mon[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["money"] = f"{Money}"
                        mon[f"{ctx.author.id}"]["hist"] = f"{HMoney}"
                        level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"{ctx.author.id}"][f"level"] = f"{LVL}"
                        level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"{ctx.author.id}"][f"xp"] = f"{XP}"

                        with open("./cogs/currency.json", "w") as F1w:
                            json.dump(mon, F1w)

                        print(f"{ctx.author.name}\nXP: {XP}\nLevel: {LVL}")

                    XP = int(level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"{ctx.author.id}"]["xp"])

                    level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"{ctx.author.id}"][f"multi"] = f"{MP}"
                    level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"{ctx.author.id}"][f"xp"] = f"{XP}"
                    level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"{ctx.author.id}"][f"txp"] = f"{TXP}"
                    level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"{ctx.author.id}"][f"NT"] = f"{user_time}"

                    ttime = (user_time) - round(int(level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"{ctx.author.id}"]["starttime"]))

                    F.close()

                    with open("./cogs/level.json", "w") as Fw:
                        json.dump(level, Fw)

                    anlvl = int(level[f"{ctx.guild.id}"][f"{ctx.author.id}"]["level"])
                    ttimeday = int(int(ttime) / 86400)
                    ttimehour = int((int(ttime) % 86400) / 3600)
                    ttimemin = int(((int(ttime) % 86400) % 3600) / 60)
                    if ttimeday == int(1): tday = ""
                    else: tday = "s"
                    if ttimehour == int(1): thour = ""
                    else: thour = "s"
                    if ttimemin == int(1): tmin = ""
                    else: tmin = "s"
                    msgtt = f"{ttimeday} day{tday}, {ttimehour} hour{thour}, and {ttimemin} minute{tmin}"
                    if anlvl in [10, 20, 25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 300]:
                        print(f"CONGRATS! {ctx.author.mention} has made it to level {anlvl} in just {msgtt}!")


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(lvlup(client))
```

It is a bit more than what you asked, but you should be able to fix anything that breaks.

Comment: Try not to spoonfeed everything, give pointers but not everything, just a small tip for the future ;)